# TypeScript: "Pick" child definitions of a picked definition

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following interface:

```
export interface WithQueryBuilder {
  queryBuilderProps: {
    columns: { [key: string]: { enabled: boolean; label: string; key: string } };
    meta: Record<string, unknown>;
    filters: Record<string, unknown>;
    search: {
      [key: string]: { enabled?: boolean; key: string; label: string; value: null | string };
    };
    page: number;
    sort: null;
  };
}
```

I now wanna create a new interface that consists of the properties in `queryBuilderProps` and some additional ones. I tried the following:

```
interface TableProps extends Pick<WithQueryBuilder, 'queryBuilderProps'> {
  onUpdate?: () => void;
}
```

What I expected is a type like that:

```
{
   onUpdate: ...,
   columns: ...,
   filters: ...,
   search: ...,
   [...]
}
```

Instead the type looks like this:

```
{
   onUpdate: ...,
   withQueryBuilder: { columns, meta, filters, ...),
}
```

I understand why this happens, but I wonder if there is a way to "pick" all the child definitions instead of the `queryBuilderProps` as a whole. Kinda like a spread operator for TypeScript.

Does anything like that exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use an `indexed access type` to look up a specific property on another type:

> type Person = { age: number; name: string; alive: boolean }; type Age
> = Person["age"];
> type Age = number
>
> [TypeScript Handbook: Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)

You may still use `interface` for your `TableProps` as follow:

```
export interface WithQueryBuilder {
  queryBuilderProps: {
    columns: { [key: string]: { enabled: boolean; label: string; key: string } };
    meta: Record<string, unknown>;
    filters: Record<string, unknown>;
    search: {
      [key: string]: { enabled?: boolean; key: string; label: string; value: null | string };
    };
    page: number;
    sort: null;
  };
}

// Here is the important part, this is the correct way to get the sub-type
type QueryBuilderProps = WithQueryBuilder['queryBuilderProps']

// You can still use interface here
interface TableProps extends QueryBuilderProps {
  onUpdate?: () => void;
}

const obj: TableProps = {
    onUpdate() {},
    columns: {
        "key": { enabled: true, label: `label`, key: `key` },
    },
    meta: {},
    filters: {},
    search: {},
    page: 1,
    sort: null,
}

// The following will throw error:
//   An interface can only extend an identifier/qualified-name with optional type arguments.(2499)
interface TableProps2 extends WithQueryBuilder['queryBuilderProps'] {
  onUpdate?: () => void;
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgdQRgAsBFAVzQE8AhchAGwBM04BvAKDjgEdKpa9ZmgAKUCGADOALnZducbBAbkAtkhns4AbQDWwKrMkwoyAOYBdWWzjAkmAEYNgTWQ4jLgmJAG44DR2AGIxNzP31DOGNTJDM4AF8En3luVWAYTFkAJWAlKCYAHmjzABo4ciRdJAgAdyQAPmSFOHRGVChNHLzC4tiyiqrahqaFSS8obGJrFIU9AxCYy2tbeycXAH43D2dvcPmo0Ni-AIcghbC4ADdMFWBZJHIGBjgAHwPFpJn4ke4wTDM7nAHqpTlAflFoDB7o8GCNvhx4hwOAB6ZFwAASaDwCEkcBI2NUkFg3ngf1gZRIOMQuPximgUFy8BqmCoeIgcAB8FpknIDgAtDAqGBgBxBcK4BRqHRGCwoGIJLiALwEIhkfiCGVobQAcj4UqEsvlUm1FiRqLgAE0IORFN4DoxnuQxogUGgsLg4MQsRxkO13XgACqOZxG3GgVBIJi4yUCaXCOXiKRybgQJAAVTATEwqE2cAAFABKOCK+pXCAIJjJREcJQaeAQBwAK1kQbWoeLyYUqYzWdQhfY8RKMyUKnUmk4zWaACIIlPlnZgy5ZCZKGUTmc4AADdcMTdlCKyTcRTcJIfNQczNIZawX5qtBjtce30bjSY3s8KP4A2QARg-3EkSFoSeIdq3NAMvRaZQGFqcw4BqB08WIcQalsKBxCgaQUTRbgAEEkBdP0cDwbA7VTBhWXDOwmDgO0KzsGAEFaNBkT4G4mIQFw+XsNJ4NVOAJEY1MbjxIU8EwKAzDUBjJAAOjzAAmAAWABOFSCx9V0MGIuBWxDRNJAU2wQAjKMVRIGMNXjHU9VjA1RAMk1O27TNs2AXN+xLMsKyrIA)

Answer (score 1):

You can access a sub-property of an `Interface` by using square brackets `[]`:

```js
type TableProps = WithQueryBuilder["queryBuilderProps"] & {
  onUpdate?: () => void
}
```

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgdQRgAsBFAVzQE8AhchAGwBM04BvAKDjgEdKpa9ZmgAKUCGADOALnZducbBAbkAtkhns4AbQDWwKrMkwoyAOYBdWWzjAkmAEYNgTWQ4jLgmJAG44DR2AGIxNzP31DOGNTJDM4AF8En3luVWAYTFkAJWAlKCYAHmjzABo4ciRdJAgAdyQAPmSFOHRGVChNHLzC4tiyiqrahqaFSS8obGJrFIU9AxCYy2tbeycXAH43D2dvcPmo0Ni-AIcghbC4ADdMFWBZJHIGBjgAHwPFpJn4ke4wTDM7nAHqpTlAflFoDB7o8GCNvhx4hwODAqGA8AAVRzOMQSSRwAC8BCIZH4gkYLCg2gARHxqHRyaJxFIqRY4AAyOTcCBIACqYCYmFQmzgAAoAJQE%20pXCAIJgIoA)